# Stencil redirect after login

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a good way to redirect to a specific page using Stencil right after logging in? It defaults to the my account, but want to send to main shop page. I know login.php?from= works, just not sure how to enforce that and looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a javascript redirect based on the referring URL, though it isn't ideal. There isn't a store setting to accomplish this.

```
if (document.referrer !== "http://www.stackoverflow.com") {
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

There are alternative scripts to accomplishing this that can be found if you look for "redirect by referring url" or "redirect based on previous page".

Comment: You should place it in the header too, and have it hide the body contents so that the user never realizes a redirect took place. Also, `window.location.pathname` might be better so you don't have to hardcode the origin store URL.